# Capture video stream and save as multiple mp4 videos in file system

Tags: java, rx-java

I am aiming to build a way to capture video stream from the network (in this case RTSP) and create 5 second videos out of the stream and save as separate MP4 files, below is not a novel approach to this but the capturing the `BuffferedImage` works however video encoding is quite faulty, it both throws `ConcurrentModificationException` and also

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create stream id 0, index 0, codec com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec@-1177292192[type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO;id=CODEC_ID_MPEG4;name=mpeg4;]
```

Here's the complete code:

```
public class App {

    static {
        String name = "WowzaBunny";
        String rtsp = "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov";
        Webcam.setDriver(new VlcjDriver(Arrays.asList(new MediaListItem(name, rtsp, new ArrayList<MediaListItem>()))));
    }

    private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "C:\\Image\\";

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(0);
        webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());

        WebcamPanel panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        panel.setFPSDisplayed(true);

        double fps = webcam.getFPS();
        if(fps == 0.0) {
            fps = 30.0;
        }
        long interval = (long) (1000 / fps);

        final long[] startTime = {System.nanoTime()};
        final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(OUTPUT_FOLDER + "video.mp4");

        List<BufferedImage> bufferedImageList = new LinkedList<>();

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            String imgName = "image.png";
            File filePath = new File(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\Image").toString() + File.separator + imgName);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = webcam.getImage();
            if(bufferedImage != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedImageList.add(bufferedImage);
                    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "JPG", filePath);
                    System.out.format("File %s has been saved in %s\n", imgName, filePath.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error - " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, 0, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        ScheduledExecutorService singleThreadScheduledExecutor =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        singleThreadScheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            try {
                bufferedImageList.forEach(bufferedImage -> {
                    bufferedImage = convertToType(bufferedImage, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                    writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4,
                            bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2, bufferedImage.getHeight() / 2);
                    long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - startTime[0];
                    writer.encodeVideo(0, bufferedImage, elapsed,
                            TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                bufferedImageList.clear();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Object o = new Object();
        synchronized (o) {
            o.wait();
        }

        writer.close();

    }

    public static BufferedImage convertToType(BufferedImage sourceImage,
                                              int targetType) {
        BufferedImage image;
        if (sourceImage.getType() == targetType) {
            image = sourceImage;
        } else {
            image = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(),
                    sourceImage.getHeight(), targetType);
            image.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
        return image;
    }

}
```

What would be the correct way to capture video stream and save into multiple mp4 video files in Java/RxJava?